# App crashes on adding setOnClickListener on button of dialogbox. [Dialog box pops by click on floating action button]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am trying to add new contact into recycler view which take name and number from user. I have already added some contacts in code. As i click on the floating action button it popup the dialog box.

My dialog box has two editText and one Button.
When i am setting a code for setOnlcickListener for Button even if there is nothing in  setOnlcickListener code the app is crashing. but if i am commenting the setOnlcickListener code it is showing the dialog box with out crashing. i think there is some problem with Submit button

I am unable to see the problem in the code.
Kindly help me out.
Here is my code

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerContact"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnOpenDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The buttonid.Setonclicklistener is causing the trouble
MainActivity.java

```java
 package com.anmol.recyclerview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     RecyclerContactAdapterCustom adapterCustom;
     FloatingActionButton btnOpenDialog;
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
     ArrayList <ContactModel> arrContact = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerContact);
        btnOpenDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDialog);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        btnOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                //Connect the Java with xml

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);
                EditText name,number;
                Button buttonSubmit;
                name = findViewById(R.id.nameid);
                number = findViewById(R.id.numberid);
                buttonSubmit = findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
                dialog.show();
                buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String numAdded="",nameAdded="";
                        if(!numAdded.equals("")){numAdded = number.getText().toString();}
                        else{Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter the number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                        if(!nameAdded.equals("")){nameAdded = name.getText().toString();}
                        else{Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter the name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                        ContactModel modelAdd = new ContactModel(nameAdded,numAdded);
                        //Whatever element we add will be added to last index
                        arrContact.add(modelAdd);
                        adapterCustom.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrContact.size()-1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        
        ContactModel model  = new ContactModel(R.drawable.a,"Anmol","701558115117");
        ContactModel model1 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.b,"A2","6515881041561818");
        ContactModel model2 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.c,"A3","16651611651568810819");
        ContactModel model3 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.d,"A3","4840188108516520");
        ContactModel model4 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.e,"A4","151411618810821");
        ContactModel model5 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.f,"A5","7512585116516822");
        ContactModel model6 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.g,"A6","56165810823");
        ContactModel model7 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.h,"A7","5151018810824");
        ContactModel model8 = new ContactModel(R.drawable.i,"A8","955810825");

        arrContact.add(model);
        arrContact.add(model1);
        arrContact.add(model2);
        arrContact.add(model3);
        arrContact.add(model4);
        arrContact.add(model5);
        arrContact.add(model6);
        arrContact.add(model7);
        arrContact.add(model8);
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.j,"A9","7018810826"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.k,"A10","7018810827"));


        adapterCustom = new RecyclerContactAdapterCustom(this,arrContact);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCustom);





    }
}
```

add_layout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Contact"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:id="@+id/nameid"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Number"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Recycle View Adapter

```java
package com.anmol.recyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerContactAdapterCustom extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerContactAdapterCustom.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ContactModel> arrContact;
    RecyclerContactAdapterCustom(Context context, ArrayList<ContactModel> arrContact)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrContact = arrContact;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Layout inflater is used to generate view from layout
        //inflate will  return the view if we give path of layout to it
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_row,parent,false);
        ViewHolder ViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return ViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imgContact.setImageResource(arrContact.get(position).img);
        holder.txtNumber.setText(arrContact.get(position).number);
        holder.txtName.setText(arrContact.get(position).name1);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrContact.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName, txtNumber;
        ImageView imgContact;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            txtNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
            imgContact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
        }
    }
}
```

ContactModel

```
package com.anmol.recyclerview;

public class ContactModel {
    int img;
    String name1,number;
   public ContactModel(int img,String name, String number)
    {
        this.name1 = name;
        this.img = img;
        this.number =   number;
    }
    public ContactModel(String name, String number)
    {
        this.name1 = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Row Layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F177A0"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/llrow"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_contact"
                android:id="@+id/imgContact"
                android:contentDescription="Contact Image"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contact Name"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Number"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>
            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>
        
        
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the custom dialog Button,EditText
Should add dialog object eg.

> Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);

and try once

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                //Connect the Java with xml

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);
                EditText name,number;
                Button buttonSubmit;
                name = dialog.findViewById(R.id.nameid);
                number = dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberid);
                buttonSubmit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
                dialog.show();
                dialog.buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String numAdded="",nameAdded="";
                        if(!numAdded.equals("")){numAdded = number.getText().toString();}
                        else{Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter the number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                        if(!nameAdded.equals("")){nameAdded = name.getText().toString();}
                        else{Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter the name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                        ContactModel modelAdd = new ContactModel(nameAdded,numAdded);
                        //Whatever element we add will be added to last index
                        arrContact.add(modelAdd);
                        adapterCustom.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrContact.size()-1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you bro This was actually the error and the if condition is also not workable. I just figured it out, thank you very much for the appreciation